# moment.js - switch language to local

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, momentjs

I try to switch the language to german, but it doesn't work :S

JS:

```
$(solutions[0]).html(moment().locale('de').subtract({h: 2, m: 10}).format('DD. MMMM YYYY'));
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yo57jnbj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the plain MomentJS library, you need to use the one which comes with locales support:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yo57jnbj/1/) a working fiddle.